# Postgres Query: Select the row with maximum value on a column from two distinct rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

```
 user_id | sum  | app_id | app_count
---------+------+--------+-----------
       1 |  100 |      3 |         1
       2 |  300 |      2 |         1
       4 | 1100 |      1 |         2
       4 | 1100 |      4 |         1
```

How do I write the query such that distinct `user_id` is selected based on the rank of `app_count`?

Here is the result I want:

```
     user_id | sum  | app_id | app_count
    ---------+------+--------+-----------
           1 |  100 |      3 |         1
           2 |  300 |      2 |         1
           4 | 1100 |      1 |         2
```

Comment: Important detail: can `app_count` be `NULL`?

Comment: No it can't be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you would use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (user_id) t.*
from t
order by user_id, app_count desc;
```

Comment: Hello @Gordon, will like to select the distinct rows and return null for app_id column if both app_count fields (user_id = 4) have the same values. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Urchboy . . . Please ask a new question with sample data and a clear explanation of what you want to do.